# Add outtro to many mp3 files

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

I regularly need to take, say, 20 mp3 files, and add another file to the end of them all.

It's an outtro for a podcast.

I'd like to automate this. I've found many articles on, say, joining many mp3s together - but not on adding an intro or outtro to many files one after another.

I'm on Windows 10.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: ffmpeg by itself can't do this. Use [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer) to join one MP3 + outro. Then run a batch/shell script to iterate.

Comment: Thanks - any info on how to create this batch / shell script?